# Finding a local max with an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

This is **not** a homework question. This is a question from a past test, in an attempt to study, and I'm completely lost.

Consider $$g(x) = \displaystyle \int_{0}^x (t^2 - 4)e^{t^2} dt$$ Find all values where $g(x)$ has a local maximum.

I know that this question isn't complicated, I just have no idea how to start.

I'm going to *assume* I need to set $(t^2 - 4) e^{t^2}$ to $0$, which would mean the critical points are $\pm 2$. Other than that though, I have absolutely no idea. Any help would be greatly appreciated (step by step would be amazing!)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you already know that the extrema will occur at those $x$ where $g'(x)=0$, so $\pm2$. To find out if you are dealing with a maximum, minimum, or inflection point, inspect the sign of $g''(x)$. At a maximum, the slope is decreasing, so $g''(x)<0$.

$$g''(x)=2xe^{x^2}(1+x^2-4)\\
\implies g''(-2)=-4e^2$$

So the maximum occurs at $-2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Check second derivative to ensure that its negative.